# PROBLEMAS PARA CONSULTAR MI WEB MEDIANTE IP PUBLICA

Tags: web, redes

Tengo un problema con el enlace a mi sitio web, tengo un servidor en el cual alojé mi sitio web utilice el IIS en Windows 10. Al principio funcionó bien, hasta hace unos días que dejó de funcionar.

***El sitio web lo estaba visualizando a través de la IP Pública*** que me proporcionaba el módem, pero ahora ya no esta funcionando.

Tengo aperturado el puerto en el módem, pero ni así funciona.

Qué podría ser?

Comment: Por lo regular los proveedores de internet dan IPs dinámicas. Seguramente tu IP pública ha cambiado.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es muy amplia, además parece un problema de configuración y no un problema de programación, tal como se establece en el [help/on-topic]. Muchos ISP trabajan con valores dinámicos para las IP públicas, ¿has verificado que la IP asignada por tu proveedor sea la misma que tenías configurada inicialmente? Por otro lado, te aconsejo contratar algún servicio de redirección como por ejemplo NOIP.com. Saludos

Comment: Como dice @Sal, a menos que hayas pagado por ello, tu IP no es fija. A menos que uses servicios como Dyndns o el viejo no-ip (que creo ambos murieron) para tener algún dominio resolviendo tu IP cada vez, tendrás que revisar cuál es tu IP cada día que enciendas tu equipo

Comment: La ip pública si cambió, en anteriores ocasiones solo con consultar esa ip sin realizar ningún cambio en la configuración del IIS, nuevamente el sitio lo tenía en línea, pero ahora no se por qué no está funcionando.